# PostgreSQL - declare variable and change its value multiple times

Tags: postgresql, variables

It's a disaster that I, coming from MySQL and T-SQL, cannot figure out from documentation (0 real examples) and stackoverflow (0 real examples) how to deal with the most basic variable management in PostgreSQL.

Code below causes an error `ERROR: duplicate declaration...`

```
declare invalidThirdUser boolean := 'false';
    
invalidThirdUser = (select 'true' where NEW.sender_id not in(
    select user1_id from thread where id = NEW.thread_id
    union all
    select user2_id from thread where id = NEW.thread_id
));
```

I tried

`invalidThirdUser = (select...`

`invalidThirdUser := (select...`

`set invalidThirdUser = (select...`

`select invalidThirdUser = (select...`

How painful is assigning a new value to variable in postgres?
Thanks.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], in this case the `CREATE` statements of the table (paste the **text**, don't use images) and a `DO` block where you declare and assign to the variable (dito). Instead of the `DO` block a simple function definition would do to but is more complicated.

Comment: And by the way, the literals for Booleans are simply `true` and `false`, there's no need for the `'` which makes them actually string literals that get -- unnecessarily -- implicitly casted.

Comment: And you can omit the subquery. Just `new.sender_id NOT IN (...)` is an expression that already evaluates to a Boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple example, how to deal with the most basic variable management in PostgreSQL:

```
do $$
declare
    invalidThirdUser boolean DEFAULT FALSE;
begin
    RAISE NOTICE '%', invalidThirdUser; -- check variable's current value
    
    invalidThirdUser := TRUE; -- set new value  
    RAISE NOTICE '%', invalidThirdUser; -- check variable's current value
    
    SELECT FALSE INTO invalidThirdUser; -- set new value  again, but using SELECT..INTO way
    RAISE NOTICE '%', invalidThirdUser; -- check variable's current value

end; $$ language plpgsql
```

Comment: Why it's impossible to declare variable inside begin...end block? It's like to be forced to declare variables outside function block in programming.

Why it's impossible to select a variable to output is as single result set used by 3rd party  applications?